# C++ - something like with keyword in python

Tags: python, c++

Well i have some abstraction around opengl shaders and i want to use them this way:

```
WITH_SHADER(shader_name) {
 // here will be gl commands
}
```

it should automatically bind/unbind that shader from current gl context.
Bind before that compound statement and unbind after that.

Can i construct this macro in C++ somehow?

Comment: You can construct such a macro. I did, thinking I would find it useful. After that it's been used exactly 0 times. But if you want to try it, note that "bind" and "unbind" map to respectively construction and destruction in C++. So all you need is a macro to declare a practically "unnamed" (no name conflict) variable in a local scope. `if` and `while` are nice constructs for introducing such local scope.

Comment: An alternative to `WITH_SHADER(blah blah)` is to simply declare `Shader blahshader_usage;`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The closest thing would be [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization).

Build a class `WithShader` that encapsulates your shader :

- Bind the shader in the constructor
- Unbind it in the destructor

Usage example:

```
{
  with_shader ws(shader_name)
  // use your shader
}
// binding and unbinding occured automatically, thats RAII.
```

---

**Note:**

RAII is not trivial in general, pay attention to the copy and assignment constructors

Comment: looks cool, but i am not sure if that destructor is executed immediately, so it can be maybe problem, i must check it

Comment: The braces which enclose the code will ensure the destructor is executed when the closing brace is reached.

Comment: It is. This pattern is used pretty extensively for scoped mutexes (and scoped anything really)

Comment: IMHO RAII classes should probably delete their copy constructors and assignment operators. Just to prevent some hidden bugs.